# Error when paying with iDeal: "Signature not supplied"

Tags: api, adyen

I set up a test account with Adyen. I try to make a payment through the test API. The following payload is given to the following endpoint:

```
https://checkout-test.adyen.com/v37/payments
```

Payload / body:

```
    {
        amount: {
            currency: "EUR",
            value: price
        },
        countryCode: "NL",
        shopperLocale:"nl_NL",
        reference: description,
        paymentMethod: {
            type: "ideal"
        },
        returnUrl: "https://xxx.nl",
        merchantAccount: "xxxxx"
    }
```

A response is returned with the redirect url, as expected. When I go to that URL, I can choose between different banks as expected. Only, when I choose a bank to pay with, the page tells me `Error: Signature not supplied`. What does this mean? What must I do to finalize my test payment succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

The Checkout API expects you to provide the UI/Visuals for selecting and collecting details of payment methods. This mean you will need you to collect the shopper's choice of ideal bank.

You can determine the required fields from /paymentMethods.

Returned from /paymentMethods

```
{
  "paymentMethods":[{
      "name":"iDEAL",
      "type":"ideal",
      "details":[{
          "key":"issuer",
          "type":"select",
          "items":[{
              "name":"Test Issuer",
              "id":"1121"
            },
            ...
          ]
      }]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Presuming you select the "Test Issuer", your payload/body would include a `paymentMethod.issuer` of **1121**

```
{
    amount: {
        currency: "EUR",
        value: price
    },
    countryCode: "NL",
    shopperLocale:"nl_NL",
    reference: description,
    paymentMethod: {
        type: "ideal",
        issuer: "1121"
    },
    returnUrl: "https://xxx.nl",
    merchantAccount: "xxxxx"
}
```